# Question about nonuniform continuity criteria

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and let $f:  A \to \mathbb{R}$. Then the following statements are equivalent:
>
> i) f is not uniformly continuous on A
>
> ii) There exists an $\epsilon_0 > 0$ such that for every $\delta > 0$ there are points $x_{\delta}, u_{\delta}$ in $A$ such that $|x_{\delta} - u_{\delta}| < \delta$ and $|f(x_{\delta}) - f(u_{\delta})| \geq \epsilon_0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
>
> iii) There exists an $\epsilon_0 > 0$ and two sequences $(x_n)$ and $(u_n)$ in $A$ such that $\lim(x_n - u_n) = 0$ and $|f(x_n) - f(u_n)| \geq \epsilon_0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$

---

I have a question about iii) and I want to check that my understanding is correct here. I am not sure about why $\lim(x_n - u_n) = 0$ is important. From ii), there are points $x_{\delta}$ and $u_{\delta}$ that are in the same $\delta$ neighborhood. Since the neighborhood is the same, then these points also share a the same limit (which makes the limit unique) within the $\delta$-neighborhood (?).

This means that two sequences $(x_n)$ and $(u_n)$ can be defined such that they converge to the same point and $\lim(x_n) = \lim(u_n)$, but then $|f(x_n) - f(u_n)|$ should also equal 0 too, but since it is greater than $\epsilon_0$, the importance here is that $f(x_n)$ is growing a lot faster than $f(u_n)$ even though the sequences both share the same limit. Is that the essence of not being uniform continuous?

Comment: I suggest that you work through a concrete example. Consider, for instance, $A = \Bbb R$ and $f(x) = x^2$, and $\epsilon_0 = 1$, and see exactly what each of the three statements translate to in that particular case, and see why they are basically saying the exact same thing.

Comment: This question arose from working on a concrete example so I tried to make the question  more general because I don't think I am grasping the importance between convergence, limits, continuity, and uniform continuity. I was trying to show that xsinx is not uc and was only able to show it using iii), but wasn't able to show it for ii)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that part is important, if you read Tao's book, you will get the notion of *equivalent sequences*.

Two sequences $(a_n)_{m},(b_n)_{m}$ are equivalent if  $\forall N\geq m$, $\exists u \geq N$ such that $\forall v \geq u$, $ ~|a_v-b_v|\leq \epsilon$ for any (small) $\epsilon$.

Now try to prove this, If $f$ is uniformly continuous, whenever two sequences $(a_n),(b_n)$ are equivalent, $f(a_n),f(b_n)$ are also equivalent.

Notice that two sequences are equivalent *only if* $\lim_{n \to \infty} (a_n-b_n)=0$, as per the definition(note that its not mandatory for $\lim a_n$ and $\lim b_n$ to separepately exist!)